Flutter, нужно ли шифровать запросы?
Изучаю Flutter.
Хочу сделать отдельное приложение для админов и для клиентов.
У клиентов планируется оплата услуг, у админов регулировка длительности услуг (списывание с абонементов).
Это самые ответственные операции.
Не где нет понятной информации про пеердачу данных по зашифрованным каналам.
Есть Пининг SSL, но как я понял используют только банки.
Как я понимаю, по умолчанию запросы идут на бекенд незашифрованными.
А как же токены (админов например), если их прехватят на пути запроса?
Как это делается на практике?
Бекенд делают с SSL?
И запросы отрпавляют на HTTPS?
Или никто их не шифрует?
Как вы делаете в своих проектах?

Голый http сейчас используется разве что если все внутри локальной сети работает. Если через интернет - обязательно https должен быть, тем более для критичных вещей типа оплаты.

Спасибо, короче https по любому.

Разница между HTTP и HTTPS заключается в одном ключевом аспекте: безопасности.  HTTPS – это по сути HTTP с добавленным уровнем шифрования, обеспечиваемым протоколом SSL/TLS (сейчас чаще используется TLS).
HTTP (HyperText Transfer Protocol):

Незащищенный протокол: Данные передаются в открытом виде.  Представьте себе открытку – любой, кто перехватывает ее по пути, может прочитать сообщение.
Порт 80:  По умолчанию HTTP использует порт 80 для коммуникации.
Уязвимости:  HTTP уязвим для различных атак, включая:

Подслушивание (Eavesdropping):  Злоумышленники могут перехватывать данные, передаваемые между браузером и сервером, например, пароли, данные кредитных карт, личную информацию.
Man-in-the-Middle (MitM) атаки:  Атакующий может внедряться в соединение между браузером и сервером, изменяя передаваемые данные или перенаправляя пользователя на поддельный сайт.
Внедрение данных (Data Injection):  Злоумышленники могут внедрять вредоносный код в передаваемые данные, что может привести к выполнению вредоносных скриптов на стороне клиента.



HTTPS (HyperText Transfer Protocol Secure):

Защищенный протокол:  Данные шифруются с помощью SSL/TLS, что делает их нечитаемыми для третьих лиц. Представьте себе запечатанный конверт – только получатель с ключом может прочитать сообщение.
Порт 443: По умолчанию HTTPS использует порт 443.
SSL/TLS сертификат:  HTTPS требует наличия SSL/TLS сертификата на сервере. Этот сертификат подтверждает подлинность сайта и содержит открытый ключ для шифрования.
Преимущества:

Конфиденциальность: Шифрование защищает данные от подслушивания.
Целостность данных:  Гарантирует, что данные не были изменены во время передачи.
Аутентификация:  Подтверждает подлинность сервера, что защищает от фишинговых атак.
SEO:  Поисковые системы, такие как Google, отдают предпочтение сайтам с HTTPS, что повышает их рейтинг.
Доверие пользователей:  HTTPS повышает доверие пользователей к сайту, отображая значок замка в адресной строке браузера.



Почему в современных приложениях необходимо использовать HTTPS:
В современном мире, где безопасность данных крайне важна, использование HTTPS стало стандартом.  Передача любой чувствительной информации, такой как пароли, данные кредитных карт, личные данные, должна осуществляться только по HTTPS.  Использование HTTP в таких случаях подвергает пользователей огромному риску.
Что будет, если использовать HTTP:

Уязвимость к перехвату данных: Все передаваемые через HTTP данные могут быть перехвачены злоумышленниками. Это особенно опасно для сайтов, где пользователи вводят личную информацию.

Проблемы с доверием: Современные браузеры помечают сайты с HTTP как «незащищённые». Это вызывает недоверие со стороны пользователей, и они могут отказаться взаимодействовать с таким сайтом, особенно если требуется вводить чувствительные данные.

Низкие позиции в поисковой выдаче: Поисковые системы могут понижать рейтинг сайтов, использующих HTTP, что негативно скажется на видимости сайта и его трафике.

Отсутствие защиты от взлома: Без HTTPS злоумышленники могут легко подменять контент сайта, внедрять вредоносный код или перенаправлять пользователей на фальшивые страницы.


